# /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found while upgrading to glibc 2.15

Tags: rhel, glibc

Need upgrading the glibc from 2.12 to 2.15 on a RHEL 6.3 system.

```
[root@ipv-vm rpm]# rpm -Uvh glibc-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm glibc-common-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:glibc-common           ########################################### [ 25%]
/usr/sbin/build-locale-archive: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/sbin/build-locale-archive)
/usr/sbin/build-locale-archive: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/sbin/build-locale-archive)
   2:glibc                  ########################################### [ 50%]
   3:glibc-headers          ########################################### [ 75%]
   4:glibc-devel            ########################################### [100%]
```

After the installation, seem the /usr/sbin/build-locale-archive can be launched.

Could you let me know whether the message is a real error? And if yes, how to fix it?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a real error, but a temporary one: it occurred because `glibc-common` was installed before `glibc`, so the updated C library itself wasn’t available yet when the updated `build-locale-archive` ran.

You could re-install `glibc-common` to re-run the post-installation setup:

```
rpm -Uvh glibc-common-2.15-60.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

(I haven’t checked whether that is necessary, but it won’t do any harm.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to re-installed the glibc-common and system just told me that the package is already installed.